# Error reading postgresql 8.4 database with pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have an old postgreSQL database running locally on my machine (localhost:5432), with postgreSQL 8.4

In the process of converting to a more modern version, I first tried to install a more modern version of postgreSQL, namely a pgSQL 12.2.4 with pgAdmin 4, freshly installed using the entrepriseDB installer.

At that point, I can access my 8.4 database with pgAdmin III, without any issue.

However with pgAdmin 4, I cannot access my tables. Namely: I can connect to the server, and view a list of databases. And I can "open" a database and see all the objects in it, and everything seems to be there, the tables are there. But whenever I try to read the properties of a table, I get the following error:

ERREUR: entrée manquante de la clause FROM pour la table « typ »
LINE 57: typ.typrelid AS typoid,

(sorry, french locales)

I can, however count rows and view the data (right click -> view/edit data) but I cannot run SQL on any of the tables (on pain of the same error).

The problem occurs with all the tables in several databases hosted on the same server - some are postGIS and some are plain, no difference.

Thanks for the hints !

Comment: pgAdmin 4 does not support discontinued Postgres versions. [Quote from the homepage](https://www.pgadmin.org/features/) "*PostgreSQL 9.5 and above*"

Comment: Well, that explains. Thanks a lot ! I will have a follow-up question re. uploading my 8.4 dump into 12, but I'll make it another post.